# Как отследить нажатие клавиши 1 раз по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как прервать отслеживание клавиши клавиатуры после нажатия на клавишу 1 раз для последующего использования.

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import keyboard


main_form = ctk.CTk()
main_form.geometry("1200x600")
main_form.title("Test")
tabview = ctk.CTkTabview(master=main_form)
tabview.pack(pady=20, padx=40, fill='both', expand=True)
tabview.add("Test")
tabview.set("Test")


def Keybind_choose():
    def print_pressed_keys(e):
        print(e.name)

    keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
    keyboard.wait()


b_button = ctk.CTkButton(master=tabview.tab(
    "Test"), text='Keybind', command=Keybind_choose)
b_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=12)

b_lable = ctk.CTkLabel(master=tabview.tab("Test"), text="Your Keybind: ")
b_lable.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=12)


main_form.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter и так может отслеживать нажатие всех клавиш, зачем вам keyboard?

Comment: @СергейКох я не знал об этом, можно подсказать как?

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/keysyms.html

Comment: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/key-names.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517655/how-to-bind-keycode-of-key-in-tkinter

Comment: @СергейКох как выйти из цикла отслеживания main_form.bind('<Key>', key_handler) потому что мне нужно отследить только первое нажатие.

Comment: В функции отключите привязку - unbind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195729/tkinter-understanding-unbind-function